# I have a shared folder called "Foldername" that shows up on another computer as "Foldername-2"

Tags: finder, folders

I shared a folder on my computer, called "Foldername". My account on the computer is UserA, my wife's account is UserB. I gave UserB read+write access on Foldername, and 
clicked the "shared folder" box.

On my wife's compuer, I log in to account UserB, and do "Connect to Server" and select my computer. It asks for the password for UserB, and it connects. In the dialog to select what folder to connect to, it lists "Foldername-2".

I have searched both macs for anything named "Foldername" and there is only the one. Any idea what is causing this? It's not a huge deal since the folder appears to work, it just worries me that the OS seems to think there is a duplicate somewhere in the system.

Comment: wife can't be user **B** :) /kidding/ ;)

Comment: Hahha!!!!!!! :)

Comment: Not a real answer, but try restart both mac's. It is in 99% cases not needed, but now the mac probably remember some old mount-points (shared dirs) when you trying sharing somewhat before. But i'm can be fully wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check all the folders which your machine is sharing via:

System Preferences > Sharing > File Sharing

There, on **Shared Folders** list, you can see all shared folders and resolve the naming conflict by providing unique names for each one of them.

Comment: There were old entries in the File Sharing list; not sure why they weren't cleaned out. Seems to be fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `-#` suffix is appended to an item in OS X when another item with an identical name already exists in that directory. Is there a chance you're enabling a shared folder that's named exactly the same as a folder that already exists in that directory?

Comment: There was only one file with that name. It turns out there were just duplicate entries in the File Sharing list for some reason.